# Pop up the file to be download on clicking the link

Tags: file, download

I am trying to make the .txt, .xml,.sql files be downloadable in the same page just like .zip,.docx files which are pop up and ask "do you want to download this file?".
I have researched and found that the windows default option for these files are open in new browser but I just want to be download in the same page. I have attached the image just like that I need to pop up when clicking those .txt,.xml,.sql files.[image]
How can this be done? Anyone have idea for this.

[image]

Comment: I just want to force download such extension files in the same page. If anyone have idea please share it. Thanks, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        I have corrected by my own. Just putting the code below will successfully pop up any files to ask whether to download or not. This is my new code.
    The download.php contains the code below:

        <?php
        $filename = $_GET["file"];
        $contenttype = "application/force-download";
        header("Content-Type: " . $contenttype);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\";");
        if($_GET['path'] == 'new_uploads')
        readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."50dl/admin_panel_new/assets/plupload/new_uploads/".$filename);
        else
        readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."50dl/admin_panel_new/assets/plupload/assessment_uploads/".$filename);
        exit();
        ?>

And the file.php contains this code:

<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/plupload/assessment_uploads/<?php echo $files->file_name?>" title="DOWNLOAD IMAGE" height="100" width="100" onClick="window.location.href='<?php echo base_url();?>logos/download?file=<?php echo $files->file_name?>&path=assessment_uploads'" class="download"/>

This will correctly sort out the current issue.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use this and it will work like a charm . 
<?php
        $filename = $_GET["file"];
        $contenttype = "application/force-download";
        header("Content-Type: " . $contenttype);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\";");
        if($_GET['path'] == 'new_uploads')
        readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."50dl/admin_panel_new/assets/plupload/new_uploads/".$filename);
        else
        readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."50dl/admin_panel_new/assets/plupload/assessment_uploads/".$filename);
        exit();
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the headers in the code where file download is requested.

```
$task = isset($_REQUEST['task']) ? $_REQUEST['task'] : ''; 
if ($task == 'download'){
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($_REQUEST['file_name']));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($_REQUEST['file_name']));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($_REQUEST['file_name']);
    exit;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but no luck. I have already tried this but this will only download the .docx, .zip files but images (with extensions .jpg,.gif,.png etc) will open in new browser and then we have to download that file which is not what I wanted. I just want to make the pop up to ask for "download the file".

Comment: I used this one for the image download. Check your Content-Type in header.. It should be application/octet-stream

Comment: Yes, the above code is OK for image download but for all type extensions there is still problem with this. I need to be able to pop up to ask to download that file but not directly open in the new browser. But anyway thanks for your answer. I have solved it. :)